# Styling tikz-timing signal lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-timing

I'm using the `tikz-timing` package and would like to apply either `snakes` type of styling, or say the `double` for double lines to signal lines. Consider the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,snakes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows} 
\usetikztiminglibrary{advnodes}

\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/nodes/advanced,]
  %
  % start timing diagram
  %
  \textcolor{green}{ClockA} & [green] H N(ca01) 
    C N(ca02) C N(ca03) C N(ca04) C N(ca05) C N(ca06) C N(ca07) C N(ca08) \\ %
  \textcolor{orange}{ClockB} & [orange,snake=zigzag,double] L N(cb01) 
    C N(cb02) C N(cb03) C N(cb04) C N(cb05) C N(cb06) C N(cb07) C N(cb08)  \\ %
  %
  % end timing diagram
  %
  % there must NOT be an uncommented line before \extracode!
  %
\extracode
  \tablerules
  %\tablegrid
  \begin{background}[line width=0.35pt]
    \draw[snake=zigzag,double] (ca01) -- (cb01) ; 
  \end{background}
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

which results in the following timing diagram:

[image: Sample image]

Obviously, the `snakes` and `double` work for normal lines, but not for signals.

Is there a possibility to also 'style' the signal diagram lines in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The support for the line decorations is very limited in `tikz-timing`.
The reason is that the timing symbols are not drawn as one drawing path but using multiple ones. Therefore the previous style settings are getting lost most of the time a new timing character is used. The `L` and `H` characters are different here and are actually drawn in one path.

The first style options at the very beginning are global for the whole line, but unfortunately TikZ seems to require to put many of the decoration styles as local option to the actual `\draw` command. Therefore your code doesn't work as expected. A few styles, like the `line width` is explicitly copied from one drawing path to the next by `tikz-timing` but this doesn't help you with decorations.

You can however add certain styles to the style definitions of the timing characters. These are called `/tikz/timing/<char>` and can be modified like shown below. Note that there is not styles for `H` and `L` characters at the moment. I might change this in the future and maybe also add one style which is used by every character. This should simply things like that.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\renewcommand{\PreviewBorder}{2mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\tikzset{timing/c/.append style={snake=zigzag}}
\tikzset{timing/t/.append style={double}}
\tikzset{timing/d/.append style={snake=zigzag}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
    A &  5{hl} 5{C} 2D{A} \\
    B &  5{hl} 5{T} 2D{B} \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

I now made some minor changes to `tikz-timing` to provide a `timing/every char` style which is used for every timing character. A second one `timing/every bg` is used for every background (like for `U`). The `H` and `L` character now also have an own style. However they do not start a new drawing path so `HL` combinations will be drawn with the last used style.

I have to test this further before I can publish it on CTAN. Feel free to download it from the SVN repository. Simply download the [DTX](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/tikz-timing/export/2191/dev/tikz-timing.dtx) and [INS](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/tikz-timing/export/2191/dev/tikz-timing.dtx) file and then run the INS file through `latex` in order to extract the package files. Do not hesitate to contact me by PM if you find any issue with this version.

The new styles can be used like that and should work with decorations:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\renewcommand{\PreviewBorder}{2mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\tikzset{timing/every char/.append style={double}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
    A &  5{hl} 5{C} 2D{A} Z \\
    B &[timing/every char/.style={snake=zigzag}]  5{hl} 5{T} 2D{B} Z \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Result]

Comment: Fantastic, @Martin Scharrer - thank you for the explanation! The reason why I was asking for something like this, is that I have this (relatively) complicated diagram, where I'd like to indicate groups of signals; for my purposes, I color them differently and it works well. However, I get complaints when relying on color for publishing (grayscale is preffered) - but on this diagram I already used plenty of gray.. So I hoped that by using `snake` or `double` I could add another level of distinction/grouping. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Oh, and PS: forgot to say - thanks for a most **awesome** package ! :) :) (kinda going all too fast these days :) )

Comment: @sdaau: Thanks for the nice feedback. I made some changes to the package. See my updated answer. I'm also very keen to see how people use this package, so I would be happy to get same source code of complicated diagrams.

Comment: thanks a lot for the update; it will be immensely useful for me! (however, as I'm still on texlive 2009, may take me a while 'til I get a look).. Just wanted to say - your latest example A (with `double`) is **exactly** what I had in mind :) For the snakes, looks like I prefer smaller segment amplitudes, as in  `\tikzset{timing/t/.append style={snake=zigzag,segment length=0.5mm,segment amplitude=0.25mm}}` ... Well, when I get any luck to publish that paper, I'll make sure I post a link to the diagram source here! Thanks again - and cheers! :)

Comment: @sdaau: As I said you can install it manually. Simply download the above files to you document folder and run `latex` once over the INS file. I assumed you will select smaller amplitudes for the snakes, but didn't had time to look the required settings up for the example.

Comment: Hi @MartinScharrer - sorry it took a while to get back on this, hope tex.se bumps you `:)` Re: "_.. some source code ..._": I finally managed to publish a paper, which can be downloaded through [its webpage](http://imi.aau.dk/~sd/phd/index.php?title=AudioBareBonesFPGA); and the source code of the `tikz-timing` figure used there is uploaded as [ft245-timing-03.tikz](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tikz/ft245-timing-03.tikz). Many thanks again - cheers!